# Get index of an element among other elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I have a set of divs:

```
<div class="index-me"></div>
<div class="ignore-me"></div>
<div class="ignore-me"></div>
<div class="index-me"></div>
```

How do I use jQuery `.index()` so that when I run it against the last element in this list, it returns 1, not 3? So, I want to any elements but with some certain class to be excluded from indexing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.index-me:eq(1)').index('div.index-me')
```

As the [`.index()` docs show](http://api.jquery.com/index/), you can pass a selector or element to make the index relative to:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
>   element is not found, .index() will return -1.

Comment: Yes sorry. I guess I need more coffee.

Comment: @Pointy - been there. pretty much every day ;)

Comment: Wouldn't this be pointless since you already know the index `eq(1)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - The OP wants to select the last div of that class. How he does it doesn't really matter. What's important to him is how to use index() with a selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = $('.index-me:last-child').index('.index-me');
```

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pg9XQ/

Comment: This alerts `1`, and the OP explicitly said that the desired answer is `3`, the index of the `<div>` among *all* the other `<div>` elements.

Comment: No problem, happens :)